# NServiceBus Request/Response AgumentNullException: Parameter name: session

Tags: asp.net-web-api, nservicebus

I have a .Net Web API app that is making a Request/Response type call using NServiceBus.
This is the code that makes the call:

```
var postOrderResponse = await endpoint
                       .Request<PostOnlineSalesHeaderResponse>(message, cancellationTokenSource.Token)
                       .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

And it fails with this exception:

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: session
>
> at NServiceBus.RequestResponseExtensions.d__3`1.MoveNext() in C:\BuildAgent\work\5008c1ef0abd347d\src\NServiceBus.Callbacks\RequestResponseExtensions.cs:line 93

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Uhg nevermind...I was being a dumbass....I hadn't correctly initialized the endpoint on which I was making the call.